# Access Windows Print button from IE WebDriver selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using 32bit IE Webdriver and Selenium 2.0 and IE9 (VS2010 vb.net Test project) Is it possible to pass Accept to Word documents Print screen which is invoked by javascript. Surprisingly it is not an Alert nor a Modal so i cannot access using WindowsHandle nor Alert. I am newbie to this can anyone help?

Thanks,
Gauls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use AutoIT tool, I was searching and got this - may be it help you:

[link](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/157533-fireevent-javascript-print-button-in-ie-vbnet-window/)